# Can't find react-transition-group/CSSTransition with React-Responsive-Modal. Do I need to install anything else?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use react-responsive-modal (https://github.com/pradel/react-responsive-modal) and I am getting the following error. I looked in `lib` and it does not contain `react-transition-group` folder.. this folder is in node-modules. I tried to copy the folder to `lib` and am still having an issue.

```
./node_modules/react-responsive-modal/lib/index.es.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-transition-group/CSSTransition' in '/Users/bp/Dev/frontend/node_modules/react-responsive-modal/lib'
```

**Modal Component:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal'

export default function DetailsModal({open, toggleDetailsModal}) {

  return(
    <Modal open={open} onClose={toggleDetailsModal()} showCloseIcon={false} closeOnOverlayClick={false} center>
      <p>Product Details Here</p>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

- open = True/False
- toogleDetailsModal = function

**From package.json:**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.15.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.5.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.6",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "formik": "^2.0.3",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "match-sorter": "^3.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.8.3",
    "react": "^16.10.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.9.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.1.9",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-responsive-modal": "^4.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-select": "^2.4.4",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^3.0.1",
    "react-table": "^6.10.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.0",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  }
```